# force osdk to return control authority back with 100% guaranteed way

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm developing osdk software for matrice 600 pro.

It is in debugging phase now, so the drone often becomes
out of control. When I confirm drone moves unexpectedly,
I have to force osdk to return control authority back to
remote controller as soon as possible.

I always do this with changing remote controller's flight mode switch (P->F F->P) and it had worked well.

But this time, when I run my osdk program about 5 minutes,
then I confirmed drone moving unexpected direction,
I tried changing flight mode switch(P->F F->P several times), but drone was still out of control, and at last It crashed into wood's pillar, and two propellers and a motor were broken.

What should have I done?
Are there any good ways to force osdk to return control
 authority back with 100% guaranteed way?
This is critical part, and I must do something about this.

I can not use simulator for debugging because some sensors
are connected to onboard computer, and I cannot test them in room.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra layer of safety to your code by monitoring the status of the mode switch yourself and explicitly releasing control authority when the state changes. For example - in a separate thread, you can poll the value of the mode switch from the TOPIC_RC subscription data. If the value toggles, you can send a `releaseCtrlAuthority()` command from this thread or set a flag in your main control loop that stops sending control commands.

That said, the mode switch toggle should always work and this appears to be more of a bug in firmware than anything else. Please raise a bug report with DJI dev support.

Comment: Do you mean that I tried right way, and adding your plan may be no effect?

Comment: This is my flight log at that time(FLY397.DAT or FLY399.zip may be the one ) 
Do you have any suggestion?
(I already submitted them to DJI support,too.)

http://www2.koyahatataku.com/drone/FLY397.DAT
http://www2.koyahatataku.com/drone/FLY398.zip
http://www2.koyahatataku.com/drone/FLY399.zip
http://www2.koyahatataku.com/drone/FLY400.zip

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar incident with a Matrice 600 Pro. Check that you still have 'Enable Multiple Flight Modes' set using the DJI GO App. Without this switch enabled, the flight mode switch does not work as expected, will not change modes, and there is nothing output by the SDK to indicate that the switch has changed.

We use this in conjunction with a separate 'safety monitor' that releases control on mode switch change using the appropriate DJI-SDK-ROS topic (/dji_sdk/display_mode), but the published value only changes if 'Enable Multiple Flight Modes' is enabled in the DJI Go app.

Comment: Yes, I had already checked DJI GO Apps Enable Multiple Flight Modes setting.Though this trouble had occured.